# Running only one background thread in google appengine backend

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, google-app-engine

As mentioned in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Background_threads) I am running a background thread in a backend with 1 instance infinitely for some continuous background processing.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager;
import java.util.concurrent.AtomicLong;

AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

Thread thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        counter.doStuff()
        Thread.sleep(10);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted in loop:", ex);
    }
  }
});
thread.start();
```

I have tied this code to _ah/start endpoint so that it gets executed once the instance is started. However while running in local server I see _ah/start request is coming in multiple times during the runtime and it starts multiple such thread . I need only one thread to exist at a time to reduce contention in my background processing.

Is there any way to catch hold of the existing bg thread and check if its running so that new thread creation can be avoided ?

**Update** 
After uploading this code to cloud I also observed that every time _ah/start is invoked on the backend it spawns a new thread as part of _ah/background endpoint and keeps running . In this way there would be many threads running together if we fail to stop the earlier ones.

Comment: One way to stamp the time in a class member variable and check if it is recent while trying to create a second thread

Answer (score 2):

A backend instance might not be what you need.

Here is the thing: you want to run infinite processing on the server. A backend is not meant for that. You might want to consider spinning off a VM on Compute Engine for that specific scenario.

A backend is for running long operations in the background. These operations are usually requested by the user. Your case is different, and that's why I'd consider the VM scenario.

Anyway, specifically to the problem you are having, your instance running the thread is not actually receiving multiple _ah/start requests. Each instance receives only one of these requests. However, the system is trying to spin off multiple instances with several _ah/start requests. I'm not sure why, but apparently something is asking for that backend to come up multiple times.

What you can do to avoid multiple threads in memory is add a flag in Memcache (which is shared for all the backends) whenever one thread runs. Every time the thread starts, check that the flag doesn't exist. If it does, don't start the thread.

Make sure you also implement the _ah/stop request to remove the flag from memcache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks . Yes I will ultimately go to GCE somdeday, however was just curious what is going on here. you are right _ah/start is called only once in cloud, its the dev server in which this endpoint is called multiple times even with a single backend (simulated at a different port). Now I will probably need a mechanism to make sure the a new thread runs in case one thread abruptly stops due to some reason.

Comment: Also as I mentioned in the comment to the question can I rely on the class member variable to set the flag. I think there will one such instance of the class as its sprint injected.

Comment: If you have two instances running (each one taking care of a Thread), the class variable of one won't be visible for the second (they will be running in separate processors). Memcache is your only solution here. Your flag can be a timestamp that gets updated every 3 seconds or so. When you get an _ah/start check if the flag has been updated recently, and if not, you can start your thread. If it's updated, you know there's another thread running already.

Comment: Yeah the time based checking is what I did (as updated in the question ). Only one instance of backend is what I am using , otherwise these would be datastore contention . The whole purpose batching the operations is to avoid contention. Lately I have trouble with memcache eviction